# Could not find the correct Provider<X> above this ModalBottomSheet Widget

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I'm new to flutter and I'm trying to understand How to use provider state management in an application which users `Moor` to save some data into `sqlite` table. My application is a task recording application. I'm getting the above error in my widget tree when I open my bottom sheet add a task. I'm using `provider: ^4.3.1`

```
class TaskView extends StatelessWidget {
  DateTime selectedDate = DateTime.now();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Provider<TaskViewModel>(
        create: (_) => TaskViewModel(),
        child: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text('Tasks'),
            ),
            body: Text("Temporary body!"),
            floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
              onPressed: () {
                showMaterialModalBottomSheet(
                  context: context,
                  builder: (context, scrollController) => Container(
                    child: bottomSheet(context),
                  ),
                );
              },
              child: Icon(
                Icons.add,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
              backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
            )
        )
    );
  }

  Widget bottomSheet(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(
          left: 16.0,
          top: 16.0,
          right: 16.0,
          bottom: 16.0 + MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: <Widget>[
          TextField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              border: OutlineInputBorder(),
              labelText: 'Task',
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 8),
          TextField(
            readOnly: true,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              border: OutlineInputBorder(),
              suffixIcon: IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.date_range, color: Colors.grey),
                onPressed: () => _selectDate(context),
              ),
              labelText: 'Date',
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 8),
          Align(
              alignment: Alignment.topRight,
              child: context.watch<TaskViewModel>().state == ViewState.IDLE
                  ? FlatButton(
                      child: Text("Save"),
                      color: Colors.blueAccent,
                      textColor: Colors.white,
                      onPressed: () => _onClickInsertTask(context))
                  : _loadingButtonChild(context))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _loadingButtonChild(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 20,
      width: 20,
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
      child: CircularProgressIndicator(
          strokeWidth: 2,
          valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.white)),
    );
  }

  /// This function is responsible for displaying the date picker when user click
  /// on task due date inputFiled
  Future<Null> _selectDate(BuildContext context) async {
    final DateTime picked = await showDatePicker(
        context: context,
        initialDate: selectedDate,
        firstDate: DateTime(2015, 8),
        lastDate: DateTime(2101));

    if (picked != null && picked != selectedDate) {
      print("Date selected ${selectedDate.toString()}");
    }
  }

  /// This function is responsible for triggering insert task block event
  void _onClickInsertTask(BuildContext context) {

    var insertTask = TaskData(task: "task", dueDate: selectedDate);
    context.read<TaskViewModel>().insertTask(insertTask);
  }
}
```

The error suggested checking.

***- The provider you are trying to read is in a different route.***

I have not given the provider to s route but as the direct parent view.

***- You used a `BuildContext` that is an ancestor of the provider you are trying to read.***

I didn't understand what it means but I made the suggested fix in the error. like below

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Provider<TaskViewModel>(
        create: (_) => TaskViewModel(),
        builder: (context, child) => Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text('Tasks'),
            ),
            body: Text("Temporary body!"),
            floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
              onPressed: () {
                showMaterialModalBottomSheet(
                  context: context,
                  builder: (context, scrollController) => Container(
                    child: bottomSheet(context),
                  ),
                );
              },
              child: Icon(
                Icons.add,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
              backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
            )));
  }
```

Still get the same error. Another thing to note here is error suggested the below.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Provider<Example>(
      create: (_) => Example(),
      // we use `builder` to obtain a new `BuildContext` that has access to the provider
      builder: (context) {
        // No longer throws
        return Text(context.watch<Example>()),
      }
    ),
  }
```

But I could not find a `builder: (context)` so I used the `builder: (context, child)`. Please let me know what I should change to get this working. Thanks.

***Edit:***

**BaseModel**

```
class BaseViewModel extends ChangeNotifier {

  ViewState _state = ViewState.IDLE;

  ViewState get state => _state;

  void setState(ViewState viewState) {
    _state = viewState;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

**TaskViewModel**

```
class TaskViewModel extends BaseViewModel{

  final TaskRepository _repository = TaskRepository();

  Resource<int> insertTaskStatus;

  Future<void> insertTask(TaskData task) async {

    setState(ViewState.PROCESSING);
    var tasksCompanion = TasksCompanion(task: Value(task.task),dueDate: Value(task.dueDate));
    insertTaskStatus  = await  _repository.insertTask(tasksCompanion);
    setState(ViewState.COMPLETED);

  }

}
```

Comment: Place your providers above MaterialApp

Comment: Can you explain why this is approach is needed to implement ?. If I do that isn't it going to be common for all the screens? And this way isn't these all Viemodel objects going get create on app start. still, my provider is on the top of the widget tree so it should work fine. But not in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you call `showMaterialModalBottomSheet` in the `Scaffold` wrapped by the `provider`, the `provider` is not above both `TaskView`'s `Scaffold` and the `modalBottomSheet`. Why?

> The provider you are trying to read is in a different route.

So, it seems that the `modalBottomSheet` is on a different `route` that doesn't have a `provider` above. If you take a look at the implementation of [showModalBottomSheet](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showModalBottomSheet.html) you'll see:

> `return Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: useRootNavigator).push(_ModalBottomSheetRoute<T>(....);`

Clearly, it's a new `route`. So, to access the `provider` it should be above both `routes`. Since, the `modalBottomSheet` `route` is managed by the `MaterialApp`, you have to place the `provider` above the `MaterialApp`.

`Provider` uses `lazy loading` by default. So, objects are created when they are required and not on app start. However, if you don't want this behavior you can set `lazy: false` individually. For more info check the [offical docs](https://pub.dev/packages/provider).

Comment: Oh, That explains the error. I'm assuming from this answer you have much more experience in the flutter. Please explain this. So, in general, are all the providers provided to material apps in real-world application development? like in here using `MultiProvider` https://pub.dev/packages/provider/example. My question is isn't it creating all the provider (ViewModel) objects on the app start and create performance issues?

Comment: No. One feature of provider is that it's lazily loaded ,i.e, it'll create an object when it's needed, not when the app starts. If you go to the readme section in the link you provided you'll find "lazy loading" specified. @ChathurangaShanJayarathna

Comment: So this is the right approach. Yeah have seen that part but didn't click it in my brain. Thanks for the help. I have to wait for 16hours to give the bounty. I'll give that.

Answer (score 0):

Another Easier option, for example if you are creating a package, that is supposed to inherit to be used in Another materialApp and you wish to use showModalBottomSheet, to read context of the parent provider, you have to disable the context of the showModalBottomSheet. This will force it to use the tree that has context for the provider in the parent widget.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Provider<TaskViewModel>(
        create: (_) => TaskViewModel(),
        builder: (context, child) => Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text('Tasks'),
            ),
            body: Text("Temporary body!"),
            floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
              onPressed: () {
                showMaterialModalBottomSheet(
                  context: context,
                  builder: (_) => Container(
                    child: bottomSheet(context),
                  ),
                );
              },
              child: Icon(
                Icons.add,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
              backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
            )));
  }
```